# Create a parameterless procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a parameterless procedure that is used to take columns from a table and do some modifications to it and paste it into another table. But I am getting the following errors:
Procedure DEMO compiled

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/2       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/10      PLS-00403: expression 'NET.NETSALARY' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement
8/24      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Errors: check compiler log
My code used for this in sql is :

```
    create or replace procedure "DEMO" 
    as 
    begin 
        case when comm is null then 0.9*grosssalary 
        when comm<500 then 0.85*grosssalary 
        else 0.8*grosssalary end 
        into net.netsalary from (select salary+comm as grossSalary,comm from 
        employee) ;

         end ;
          /
```

I am trying to insert the data into column netsalary of table net.
Please mention where did I go wrong?
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server if this is an Oracle question? Spam tagging will gain you downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO net (netsalary)
      SELECT CASE
                WHEN comm IS NULL THEN 0.9 * grosssalary
                WHEN comm < 500 THEN 0.85 * grosssalary
                ELSE 0.8 * grosssalary
             END
        FROM (SELECT salary + comm AS grossSalary, comm FROM employee);
END;
```

but it won't do much good. You're inserting as many rows as there are in the `employee` table, but ALL you insert is `netsalary` value - you don't even know who it belongs to.

Without knowing tables' description, it is difficult to guess what you really want to do.

- insert? Probably employee number (or whatever that column name is) is missing
- update? That's completely different command

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yeah, u said correctly regarding the table description. But I only created one column i.e,.netsalary for the net table for sample purposes.

Comment: OK, then that's it.